# Fetch data from different DB with different login from some other DB.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 databases on same server. One is db1 and other is db2. Client sets one login for db1 and one diffrent login for db2.in this way that db1 user cannot access db2 and vice-versa. I created one stored proc in db1 that uses diffrent tables in db1 now according to reqyirement i have to use 2-3 tables of db2 in that proc.i have login diffrent login for both dbs. What is the best workaround to fetch data from db2 tables in db1 proc.

Comment: Look up "cross database ownership". Have you tried using db.schema.object notation?

Comment: It is giving error as invalid object name.

Comment: you can try with "Linked Server". [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine). Then use openquery to get data from the linked server to the "main" one

Comment: I suggest you look up cross database ownership - that's the proper method

Comment: I checked on several places but i found out that in cross db ownership there is involvement of dba. I dont have dba support here. Is there any way where i can pass credentials for that db and with query and execute that.

Comment: So.. are you allowed to create users? Give us some clues